# Type mismatch error excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error, mismatch

The goal of my code is to take the old value of a cell, and check it against a new value, if it is entered. And if the old value changes to a new value, then update the date in a cell specified.

The problem with my code is that I cannot seem to find a way to get around this error without my code breaking, thus I am having trouble trying to fix this one line of code. I have this code in two worksheets, both with their values altered for different cells. The problem is, this code DOES work only if it is for one worksheet, but when I use two with the same code, it throws a type mismatch error.

Here's my code:

```
Dim oldValue As Variant

Public Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
'My other worksheet is referencing cells E2:E100
oldValue = Me.Range("D4:D21").Value
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("D4:D21")) Is Nothing Then
Dim c As Range
For Each c In Intersect(Target, Me.Range("D4:D21"))
    'Check value against what is stored in "oldValue"
    'Type mismatch is on this line here
    If oldValue(c.Row - 3, 1) <> c.Value Then
        'Update value in column L (8 columns to the right of column D)
        c.Offset(0, 7).Value = Date 'or possibly "= Now()" if you need the time of day that the cell was updated
    End If
Next
End If
End Sub
```

I'm not sure what type mismatch error means, so I'm unable to fix this problem by myself. My question is, how can I properly update my cells without this mismatch error throwing?

EDIT: Keep in mind, one worksheet is looking for numeric data changes, and the other worksheet is looking for string value changes, I'm not sure if this matters. If I take out all the code for one worksheet, the code will work for the other, but when I put it back in, they both stop working.

Thank you.

Comment: I recognise that code!

Comment: Haha yes you do, I'm back once again :p

Comment: I'm guessing that the `Change` event has fired without the `SelectionChange` event having fired before it.  Possibly the cell that was updated was the selected cell when the workbook was opened?  You may need to force it to fire the `SelectionChange` events when the workbook is first opened, or ensure that the workbook is not saved with the selection anywhere in D4:D21.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the following code:  (Place it in the code for `ThisWorkbook`)

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Set ws1 = ActiveSheet
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        ws.Activate
        ws.Range("A1").Select
    Next
    ws1.Activate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

One warning - the Workbook_Open event is sometimes "problematic", as it occasionally fires before all the `Worksheets` are fully loaded.

Comment: @juiceb0xk - Even after closing the workbook and re-opening it?

Comment: Yes, I tried multiple times, even with the selection saved elsewhere than the cells referenced.

Comment: Hmm - each worksheet should have its own `oldValue` variable (they are local to each code module), so the values shouldn't be "interfering" with each other. Each time you move the selection it should write the existing values to the `oldValue` array, and each time you change one of the relevant cells it should be able to find the `oldValue` value to look at.  The `Type mismatch` is almost certainly because it has lost the current contents of `oldValue`.  (If you declared it as `Dim oldValue() As Variant` it would probably give a `Subscript out of range` error.)  I'm not sure what is going on!

Comment: Can you try something for me - select cell A1 in the first worksheet, then select cell A1 in the second worksheet, then start trying to change values in each worksheet.  When does it complain with the type mismatch - on the first cell change, or on the second change, or something else?  (And each time it "breaks", try selecting cell A1 on both sheets before starting again.)

Comment: That's it! When I select cells A1 in both worksheets before refreshing the cells, it updates the date and does not throw an error. If I open the workbook and cells other than A1 are not selected when first refreshing data, it throws the error.

Comment: Also, when removing `Application.ScreenUpdating`, this code works now. I'm not sure why, but you've fixed my problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: Hmm (again) - The `Workbook_Open` event I posted should cause each worksheet to select cell A1 as the workbook is opened, so that comment "If I open the workbook and cells other than A1 are not selected" worries me.

Comment: "I'm not sure why, but you've fixed my problem." - I've got no idea why either!!!  The `Application.ScreenUpdating` was there simply so you wouldn't see the code flick between each worksheet - it shouldn't be impacting the code at all.  Persisting variables is always a problem - I sometimes think that Thomas Inzina's solution to your original post (mirroring the whole sheet to another hidden sheet) might have ended up being a better solution.